# How to add Tikhonov regularization in "scipy.optimize.least_squares"?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

As the title, could anyone tell me a way to add "Tikhonov regularization" in "scipy.optimize.least_squares"? The default seems L2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way is to add more rows to your design matrix and objective vector.

In other words if you have A and b, and seek x to minimise

```
||A*x-b||
```

and you change A and b to

```
A~ = (A)
     (K)
b~ = (b)
     (k)
```

then the least squares problem: minimise

```
||A~*x - b~||
```

is minimising

```
||A*x-b||^2 + ||K*x-k||^2
```

Comment: This means I need to modify the source code of scipy.optimzie for reconstructing the square norm and including the term of regularization. Now I cannot find where is the square operation ^2 in scipy.optimize.

Comment: I dont see that you need change scipy.optimise. All you need to o is to pass A~,b~ to it instead of A,b

Comment: I understand it. Thank you.